# Laravel Query: Conditional value in Where Clause

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have this query

```
$timezone ='';

if(!empty(\Request::get('timezone')))
{
   $timezone = \Request::get('timezone')
}else
{
   $timezone = 'users.timezone'
}


$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('timezone', $timezone)
                ->get();
```

How to keep show result when where criteria empty or not defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#conditional-clauses) method:

```
DB::table('users')->when($request->timezone, function($q) {
        return $q->where('timezone', request()->timezone)
    })
    ->get();
```

> The when method only executes the given Closure when the first parameter is true. If the first parameter is false, the Closure will not be execute

Alternatively, you could use the where closure.

Comment: This what I need, thanks :)